# ListGrid scrollbar buggy on IE11 with SmartGWT 4.0 and GWT 2.6.0

Tags: java, internet-explorer, gwt, smartgwt

I spent a day trying to figure out what's wrong with the scrollbar on IE11 and no luck. The list grid is displaying all results at once and the scrollbar buttons doesn't work.

SmartGWT's showcase doesn't have that issue and the funny thing is that I created a blank page with just the listgrid in there and nothing else (no external CSS or JS), and still.. I'm wondering if there's some obscure set up that I'm not doing on my end. below is a screenshot of the bug and the code used to generate the grid:

screenshot: http://s28.postimg.org/e34118br0/smart_gwt_ie11_bug.jpg

```
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
    RootPanel.get().add(newTestListGrid());
}

private ListGrid newTestListGrid() {
    ListGrid grid = new ListGrid();  
    grid.setWidth(550);
    grid.setHeight(224);
    grid.setZIndex(50000);
    grid.setHeaderHeight(40);
    List<ListGridField> fields = new ArrayList<ListGridField>();
    fields.add(new ListGridField("studentName", "Name"));
    grid.setFields(fields.toArray(new ListGridField[fields.size()]));
    List<ListGridRecord> records = new ArrayList<ListGridRecord>();
    ListGridRecord r;
    for (int oI = 0; oI < 100; oI++) {
        r = new ListGridRecord();
        r.setAttribute("studentName", "sei la");
        records.add(r);
    }
    grid.setData(records.toArray(new ListGridRecord[records.size()]));
    return grid;
}
```

OS: Windows 7
Browser: IE 11
SmartGWT: 4.0
GWT: 2.6.0

Does anybody knows how to solve this?

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Hi Matias! I am having the same problem with ListGrid.. did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Hi @DianaAmza! this is a little while ago so honestly I don't remember what the fix was.. should've posted here, my bad.. but I think what @Darkane suggested: calling .draw() might be the fix, or try upgrading SmartGWT's version. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I tried calling draw() but no luck..Yup, probably the best solution is to upgrade GWT. I'll do that.

Comment: Try upgrading both if that's possible (SmartGWT and GWT itself), it's usually a good idea to be running the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I would say try the following:

- add your grid to some kind of layout, HLayout or VLayout. It may fix things.
- call draw().